# How can I change a uint8_t array into an array of integers?

Tags: c++, arrays, uint8t

How can I change a uint8_t array into an array of integers? For example if I want to print the numbers in the uint8_t array array_beam_sx I have to write:

```
cout<<+array_beam_sx[0];
```

to see the number. But if I want to assign the element of a uint8_t array to another uint8_t array this doesn't work:

```
array_beam_sx_girato[j]=array_beam_sx[1000-j];
```

So I was wondering if there is a way to transform the letters inside the uint8_t array into an array of numbers and the work with this one. Many thanks

`

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: If you are saying `array_beam_sx` contains characters like `'1'` and you want to turn that into numbers like `1`, then that would be `array_beam_sx[0] - '0'`

Comment: "*if I want to assign the element of a uint8_t array to another uint8_t array this doesn't work*" - it looks fine to me. In what way does it not work exactly?

Comment: it doesn't compile

Comment: error: invalid types ‘uint8_t {aka unsigned char}[int]’ for array subscript
         array_beam_sx_girato[j]=array_beam_sx[bins-j];

Comment: uint8_t is an integer, so an array of uint8_t is already an array of integers. No change is needed.

Comment: so why do I see letters instead of numbers if I don't put a + before the element?

Comment: Could you create a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example